# Google Cloud Speech Error 500 (Internal server error)

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, google-cloud-speech

I have a simple JS code running in xampp apache.

```
var rawFile;
var allText;
var byteArray = [];

rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
rawFile.open("GET", "brooklyn.flac", false);
rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
    if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
    {
        if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
        {
          allText = rawFile.responseText;
            //alert(allText);

        }
    }
     if (rawFile.status != 200) return byteArray;
        for (var i = 0; i < rawFile.responseText.length; ++i) {
        byteArray.push(rawFile.responseText.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff)
        }
     }

rawFile.send(null);

function send(){
var oAjaxReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

var payload = {
  config:{
    encoding: "FLAC",
    sampleRateHertz: 16000,
    languageCode:"en-US"
  },
  audio: {
    content: rawFile
  }
};

oAjaxReq.open("post", "https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=???", true);
oAjaxReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

//object ot json
const jsonPayload = JSON.stringify(payload);

//Length of the jsonPayload
const payLoadLength= jsonPayload.length;
oAjaxReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", payLoadLength);
oAjaxReq.withCredentials = true;

 //Send Json to Google Cloud Speech Service
 oAjaxReq.send(jsonPayload);
 }
```

I am trying to use the Google Cloud Speech API.
I am loading a local audio file with the name "brooklyn.flac", which I downloaded from "https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-samples-tests/speech/brooklyn.flac", via xmlHTTPRequest.

However, I always recieve the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
```

When I change the audio part of my payLoad object from "content: rawFile" to "uri: "gs://cloud-samples-tests/speech/brooklyn.flac" it´s working properly.

Is the error because of the "rawFile"?
If yes, how can I correctly load this local file to send it to the cloud service?

Comment: To make this code work.
Instead of loading the local file with xmlHTTPRequest, I used FileReader.
After that I could encode the content of the file with btoa(); and send it to google without any errors.
If anyone needs the source code, just contact me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** - Except for your audio content, the rest of the payload looks good to me. You most likely are not encoding the audio using `base64` (since you haven't mentioned anything about it) and hence hitting the server error. Passing the `base64` encoded version of the audio content will fix the issue.

### API types and sources for audio content

There are 2 main ways to use the Cloud Speech API:

- Using the [JSON based REST API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rest)
- Using the [gRPC based API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rpc)

Both of them support the audio content from either:

- Google Cloud Storage
- a raw file you send directly in the request.

Using Google Cloud Storage is the simplest of the 2 approaches IMO. You upload the file to GCS and you pass the URI of the file (eg. `gs://cloud-samples-tests/speech/brooklyn.flac`).

### Encoding the audio content

If you are sending the raw file as part of the request, depending on the API you're using you will need to handle the content accordingly:

- JSON based REST API [requires that the audio content be `base64` encoded](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/base64-encoding). The link also has examples on how to perform the base64 encoding in Python, Node.js and Java.
- gRPC based API supports binary file uploads and hence you can pass the raw file as-is without any additional processing.

### Google Cloud client library

I'm not sure if `Node.js` is an option, but if so - you could [use the Google Cloud client library](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/reference/libraries) (which supports Speech Recognition in Alpha only at the time of writing). This library can automatically `base64` encode the file for you and offers other convenient features too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Tuxdude!
Now I understand how all of this works, and what this error is caused by. 
I will try out both ways.

Comment: It really did work! Thank you Tuxdude, the base64 converted rawFile did the magic!